# What's a good way to make a kiosk for a 24-hour restaurant when few customers come? (wakelock , kiosk mode , task lock...)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kiosk-mode, android-8.1-oreo

The app, which should not go into the screen or cpu slip without using the tablet often and can receive mqtt messages 24 hours a day, was created using the tablet setting, excluding battery usage optimization,off screen slip setting, wakelock, wifilock, etc.

But is there a more efficient way?...

So I was looking and found the kiosk mode and task lock.

1. If i use kiosk mode or task lock, can i make the screen not turn off and cpu , network not go into the sleep?
2. Is there an easy way to prevent the screen, cpu, and network from going to sleep mode when power is connected?

Comment: What is "cpu slip"? is that like oversteer?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use battery optimizations.
You can use wake locks, either to wake up screen or CPU, as suggested in the following link:

https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock

If you use browser, it should be useful the following, to keep screen alive:
https://davidwalsh.name/wake-lock-shim